# Collapsing dict keys into one key: Python

Tags: python

So I have a bunch of dictionaries in a list, whose keys are numbers and values are string objects. something like `[{0:'tom',1:'cat',2:'apache',3:'server',4:'open', 5:'now'},...]` and I like to get something like

`[{0: 'tom cat apache', 1:'server',2:'open',3:'now'},...]` by collapsing the first 3 keys into 1 keys and adding their values. The keys may or may not be always consecutive or starting at zero.

I can do this with for loops and if statement, but my implementation seems messy. I'm sure there's a pythonic way. Thanks!

Comment: Will the keys always be consecutive and start at 0?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "first" key, dict keys are unordered.  Are you sure you don't want to use a list instead?  You might need to provide more details.

Comment: @minitech: Let assume it's the case for the sake of argument for now.

Comment: Is number 3 key missing on purpose?

Comment: -1 I'm sorry, but this question is not clear at all. How do keys 4 5 get transformed into 1 and 2?

Comment: `I can do this with for loops and if statement, but my implementation seems messy.` - I think given the ambiguity of your question - let's see your implementation even if it's *messy code*

Comment: I can't quite figure out what it is you're looking for, but it seems like you want dictionaries with ordered keys. As various others have pointed out, you can't have that with a dict--but you can with an OrderedDict from the collections module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the keys aren’t necessarily consecutive, the best way I can think of would be this:

```
items = sorted(d.items())

dict(enumerate([' '.join(b for a, b in items[:3])] + [b for a, b in items[3:]]))
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.org/VWHtgYoc)

Comment: Oh, I missed that `4` and `5` turned into `1` and `2`. How does that work? Should they be consecutive after the transformation?

Comment: Yes, they should be consecutive after the transformation

Comment: @Mike: Do you need a dict, or would a list be better/acceptable? (And Python 2, or Python 3?)

Comment: The final result should be in a list of dict. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: unhashable type` when I run this  `dict(enumerate([' '.join(b for a, b in items[:3])] + [b for a, b in items[3:]]) for items in temp)` where temp is a list of dict

Comment: @Mike: The `for items in temp` should be outside of the `dict(...)`, not inside of it.

Comment: I get a none value return in that case. Which not is correct. something is missing. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike: I don’t think that should be possible... :P Can you edit your question to add your code, please?

Comment: wanna move this to a chat? I'll you u the entire list of dicts I'm talking about.